# How to structure a GET request using HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, http-headers

I am making a rails application that will make API calls to Eventbrite, using HTTParty.

I do not know how to structure my eventbrite.rb in my \lib directory file so that I can call it in my controller.

My eventbrite.rb file so far:

```
require 'HTTParty'

class EventBriteApi
  def eventbrite
    HTTParty.get()
  end
end
```

The url I am sending a GET request to is something like this: `www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?q=concert&sort_by=best&venue.city=san francisco`

I already have an authorization token so I just need to know the format in which to structure my class, and how to actually make the right call in the controller, as well as how to grab the variables from the form in my view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use existing API libraries for EventBrite, if you just want to learn, then its cool. The best way to learn is to see how others have done it.

https://github.com/ryanj/eventbrite-client.rb/blob/master/lib/eventbrite-client.rb

@^ Go through the code and see how he has done it.